# How to enable Hibernate in 12.04?

Tags: power-management, suspend, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify policykit to allow hibernation in upower?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-modify-policykit-to-allow-hibernation-in-upower)

I just installed the new 12.04 beta on my Lenovo Ideapad U450. According to this thread [Whither hybrid suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1685/whither-hybrid-suspend) hibernate and suspend are supported, but in the power settings the option to hibernate is greyed out e.g. for what to do when closing the lid.
How can I enable it?

My goal is, that if suspend to both is not supported a behaviour something like, suspend to ram and when battery is low, suspend to disk. Is this possible?

/Kind regards 
Christian

Comment: Typically speaking, questions about Ubuntu+1 are off-topic on this site. Especially regarding features that are not working. Instead, the question linked above provides ways to get help with Ubuntu+1 as 12.04 has not been released yet. This is covered in the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) under the bullet point "This is not the right place for": `Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1)`. If you wish to discuss the merit of this question further, please visit our [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com)

Comment: Nominate to reopen: This question is not about a bug, but a decision that will be present in 12.04. Hibernate will be (is) disabled by default on all non-certified hardware. It's likely going to be a popular problem with 12.04 and answering it before launch would be helpful for lots of users.

Comment: Source bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/812394

Comment: Forget it, it's already here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-modify-policykit-to-allow-hibernation-in-upower