# How to enable Hibernate in 12.04? (Again)

Tags: power-management, suspend, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)
>   [How to enable Hibernate in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109646/how-to-enable-hibernate-in-12-04)

I just installed the new 12.04 beta on my Lenovo Ideapad U450. According to this thread [Whither hybrid suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1685/whither-hybrid-suspend) hibernate and suspend are supported, but in the power settings the option to hibernate is greyed out e.g. for what to do when closing the lid. How can I enable it?

My goal is, that if suspend to both is not supported a behaviour something like, suspend to ram and when battery is low, suspend to disk. Is this possible?

Comment: Your other question was closed because this site does not support the current alpha and beta versions. If you have questions about the currently supported versions like 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 or 11.10, feel free to ask them. If your question is about 12.04, which is not yet released to the general public, it will be most probably closed.

Comment: I bet your RAM > swap.  Your swap needs to be at least the size of your RAM, otherwise you can't hibernate, only suspend (to RAM).

Comment: Ok, I bet I would have the exact same problem in any other version too. Open Source is in great parts alpha or beta, so I think questions about things on not supported versions are valid. Would this forum be so rude if I'd have 11.10. installed?

Comment: @CS: I have swap in exactly the same size as my ram (4GB) and it is enabled. Should I make it bigger?

Comment: Anyway, I think this is what you are looking for. http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-modify-policykit-to-allow-hibernation-in-upower

Comment: @Waxolunist Posting commentary about previous questions in your question body is not the place to do this. If you have an issue with why a question was closed DO NOT open a new one, instead visit our [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com) to discuss actions taken on the main site. In fact Hibernation and Suspension issues are different between releases and between hardware. You can't say for certain if it would or would not work.

Comment: Thx, jokerdino this was the answer. So difficult? Why should I go to meta if I got a technical question. I searched, but didn't find it, but it was there, so this question is allowed, though Ubuntu+1 regarding. I just want to discuss a question if it is allowed (it is as we know now) for a day or more, if I would get the correct answer in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem is solved.  Regarding AskUbuntu... it seems pretty much like the focus here is not on helping individuals per se, but building a reference website that will be more beneficial to the community at large.  So, for example, it's important to reduce noise by weeding out duplicate posts that confound search engines and so on.  Whether you personally are helped is less important.  I'm not saying I agree with this, but it seems to be the intent of the website design and structure.

Comment: I would recommend ubuntuforums.org as a place to get individual help and discussion, although it has some of the issues AskUbuntu is designed to avoid.