# Why does my battery drains fast with Ubuntu in sleep more?

Tags: 12.04, battery

I have an Asus EEE PC 1005HA netbook dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7. When I close the lid in either OS the laptop will go to sleep. If I do this in Ubuntu and come back to the computer a few days later the battery will be completely drained. If I do it in Windows then the netbook will eventually hibernate and the battery will be fine.

Any ideas what I can do to fix the battery drain problem?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you have set the settings of *When Lid Is Closed* to **Suspend** in Ubuntu

Lets understand what Suspend means and what Hibernate means-

---

**Suspend -**

Suspend means to save the state of your machine to the **RAM** of your computer.

In this case,**RAM** is volatile memory which requires power to function.And thus it uses battery.

When you resume from *Suspend*,it is quocker than resuming from *Hibernate*

**Hibernate -**

Hibernate means to save the state of your machine to the **HARD DISK/HDD/SDD** of your computer.Now,anything saved in **HDD/SDD** does not need power to stay there.Thus no power is needed.

Resuming from *Hibernate** is slower than resuming from *Suspend*

---

So if you want your PC to act same as it does in windows when the lid is closed,

1.Go to System Settings

2.Select **Power**

3.In the *When Lid Is Closed* menu,select **Hibernate**

Comment: Windows seems to do some combination of the two. When you close the lid it suspends and then after some length of time it will convert to hibernating. Does that sound like something that can be done in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Nirmik Note, hybernate is disabled by default in 12.04.

Comment: Well i dont know if that is possible...m unsure coz i guess it does happen with mw,but i dont remember exactly if it does! But if your ultimate aim after closing the lid is to hibernate it,then you dont need the combo i guess

Comment: Looks like hybrid suspend is what I want - http://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend

Comment: I guess so !! :)

Comment: @user68186...yeah...m aware :) here is the link if necessary to enable hibernation...http://askubuntu.com/a/94963/46000