# What will be the power backend for (K)Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, power-management, suspend, hibernate

I have Kubuntu 13.04 installed. KDE uses powerdevil to manage hibernate/sleep, which in turns seems to use `pm-utils` backend. `pm-utils` is unmaintained, and broken at this point<sup>1</sup>. For example, I had to jump through many hoops to just enable in-kernel hybrid suspend which [has been present since kernel 3.6.](https://askubuntu.com/a/344879/70266)

I asked on Freenode #kde, and it seems like KDE powerdevil has been modified to accept newer backends for a while now. The order of preference is roughly systemd-login1, upower, and Solid.

Does anyone know what power backed will *buntu 13.10 use?

---

<sup>1</sup> The `pm-utils` code was last updated in 2010, and they have not been accepting patches.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of pm-utils seems to be "06 Nov 2013" from this [changelog](http://ftp-master.metadata.debian.org/changelogs//main/p/pm-utils/pm-utils_1.4.1-13_changelog).