# Is it possible to make 16.04 hibernate on lid close?

Tags: 16.04, laptop, power-management, hibernate

I recently updated to 16.04 (64 bit) and I'd really love to be able to make my laptop hibernate on closing the lid. I'm able to successfully hibernate by typing `sudo pm-hibernate` into terminal but I tend to forget to do this when tossing my laptop in my bag and then I pull out a dead computer.

I've followed the directions here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/ubuntu-16-04-shutdown-hibernate-your-laptop-lid-closed/ with no luck.
Are there any other options I can try to get my computer to automatically hibernate?

EDIT: following the instructions at the above link, I've used dconf Editor to set hibernate on lid closed and also set /etc/systemd/logind.conf to hibernate on lid switch

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend/781957#781957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it.

Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and set

```
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
HandleSuspendKey=hibernate
```

You can also use `hybrid-sleep` instead of `hibernate`.

**Don't forget to remove the `#` in front of the above two lines and also to reboot.**

Comment: So I've actually already done exactly this with no effect. I'll try hybrid-sleep to see if it does anything...

Comment: Did you remove `#` in front of the lines? And did you reboot?

Comment: Aaaaand I'm just super dumb. No, I didn't remove the #. Thank you. This fixed it.