# hibernate when lid is close

Tags: hibernate, lid

I just installed ubuntu then I installed gnome then I instaled TLP(power manegment)
now I want to hibernate the computer when lid is close.
I followed this instructions:

[Is it possible to make 16.04 hibernate on lid close? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828400/is-it-possible-to-make-16-04-hibernate-on-lid-close)

and this instructions:

[Ubuntu 16.04: Shutdown / Hibernate Your Laptop When Lid is Closed | UbuntuHandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/ubuntu-16-04-shutdown-hibernate-your-laptop-lid-closed/)

and nothing work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend working this issue in steps.

1. First,to get hibernate tested and working on your laptop, please read the [Ubuntu documentation regarding hibernation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html). **Important: make sure your swap file is larger than your physical RAM, and that it's enabled.**
2. Once you know your laptop can hibernate properly, you can assign laptop actions to trigger hibernation. In your case, you'd like to hibernate on lid close. There's plenty of documentation out in the aether on this topic, but let's go to the source documentation on this: [the systemd login configuration file manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html). Of particular interest is the section that describes the `HandleLidSwitch` option.According to the documentation, that option

   > Can be one of "ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec",
   >   "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", and "lock".

   You want `hibernate` (in my own case, I use `hybrid-sleep`). So, now it's a matter of editing the `logind.conf` file to accommodate this setting (you must be root to do this).

   In `/etc/systemd` you'll see a file called `logind.conf`. Open it for edit, and scroll down to a line that looks like this:

   `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend`

   The prepended `#` means that this line is currently disabled, so you need to remove it, and then set `HandleLidSwitch` to the correct option

   `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`

   Save the `logind.conf` file and reboot.

Comment: What is the difference between hibernate and hybrid-sleep?

Comment: In hybrid-sleep, the first-level action is to suspend, but also persist OS state to disk (like a hibernate action). If the battery fails while suspended, the OS state is not lost (as would be the case in a pure suspend action).

Comment: I cant hibernate! its so weird cause in original ubuntu (with unity) I could do that. From the moment that I changed to gnome it stoped working.
why is that?
and THANKS!

Comment: @tsachiblau, did you get through Step 1? If no, what specifically failed?

Comment: when i had unity the hibernate worked well when I closed the lid.
today I installed gnome and now it dosen't work.
I tried step number 1 and it also dosen't work.
so I think that maybe hibernate dosent work well on gnome.

anyway I have only 512MB on my swap so I don't think that I can hibernate according to what has been said above..

Comment: @tsachiblau, yes, you **absolutely** have to have a swap file or partition that will be the repository for persisting your RAM snapshot. Otherwise hibernate cannot work. BTW, I'm running Ubuntu Gnome (always have), so that's not a factor.