# Use `s2both` for suspending

Tags: suspend, 17.04

KDE uses suspend-to-ram by default.

How can I change it so it runs `s2both` instead?

I have tried [How do I use pm-suspend-hybrid by default instead of pm-suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend) but that simply blocks my machine, whereas `s2both` works.

This is why I would like KDE to simply call `s2both` instead of doing something else.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Except that that solution blocks my machine. s2both, however, works. I cannot explain why the other solution does not work on my machine, so I would like to use something that I know works.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release? `s2both` uses an entirely different suspension method (user space suspend instead of kernel suspend).

Comment: Kubuntu Release 17.04. If  `s2both` uses a different method, that might explain why it works on my system.

Comment: Since kernel suspension is actually preferred over user-space suspension and kernel developers would like to see bug reports about platforms with broken suspension, let's try to debug the former a little. What's the model of the desktop or laptop computer (if it came pre-assembled) in question or the mainboard (if it's a custom assembly). You can find out with `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX lshw -c system,bus | grep -A7 -e '^    description:' -e '^  \*-core$'`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean that the system "simply blocks" when you try hybrid suspension like in the linked question? What happens when you use `sudo systemctl hybrid-sleep` directly?