# Lid Closed Suspend then Hibernate

Tags: lid

I would love for the lid closing behavior to "suspend" for a certain amount of time (1 or 2 hours) and then "hibernate" to save battery. Is there a way to change the settings of "suspend" so that it go into "hibernate" after some time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

To start using this function you need to create a file **/etc/systemd/sleep.conf** with the next content:

```
[Sleep]
HibernateDelaySec=3600
```

Then you can test it by command:

```
sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate
```

(you can edit HibernateDelaySec to reduce delay to hibernate).
If all works fine you can change Lid Close Action, to do it you need to edit the file **/etc/systemd/logind.conf**

You need to find option *HandleLidSwitch=*, uncomment it and change to *HandleLidSwitch=suspend-then-hibernate*.
Then you need to restart logind service(wirning! you user session will be restarted) by the next command:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

Thats all! Now you can use this nice function.

Comment: Really nice to prevent power drain while on the go, but if the laptop is connected to AC all night, and  I open it  after a few hours, what's the point of finding it hibernated?
Is there a way to switch to suspend and poll the AC status every hour or so, and in case we're not connected to AC it hibernates? At least, macbooks behave like this, and actually makes sense.

Comment: @sscarduzio `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower` or `HandleLidSwitchDocked` - see `man logind.conf`.

Comment: As of systemd version 252, this option has been updated to hibernate when the battery is low. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/25269

Comment: As of systemd version v253-rc2 this feature has been reverted to the original behavior (against the desires of a very narrowminded developer named bluca thank god)