# Ubuntu 20.04 sleep-inactive-battery-type hibernate not working

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, battery, hibernate

I am trying to make my laptop go to hibernate after some inactivity but it does not work.

Hibernate (and suspend-then-hibernate, implentend via [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072504/lid-closed-suspend-then-hibernate)) are working for themselves, tried via "sudo hibernate" and "sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate".

The command

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep battery
```

yields

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys battery ['XF86Battery']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys battery-status-static ['XF86Battery']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys battery-status ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 60
org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage false
org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files index-on-battery-first-time true
org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files index-on-battery true
```

I get the message popping up after one minute, that the system will hibernate. But nothing happens. After a while (set to 5 mins) the display goes dark and the user login is screen is shown, still with the notification at the bottom of entering hibernation.

Any advice why my system is getting stuck and not going into hibernation?

**Update**: @waltinator, I tried the command "free", and this is what I get:

```
          total      used       free         shared      buff/cache   available
Mem:    15583036     2935096     7268200       74468     5379740    12248832
Swap:   16777212     1307908    15469304
```

**Update2**: I had a look at the syslog and found this:

```
Jul  2 16:53:45 XXX gsd-power[2097]: Error calling Hibernate: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied
```

Afterwards nothing is happening - guess I have to resolve this.

**Update3: I got it working! In the end it was a permission/activation issue of hibernate.**

What I did was follow this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/992878), by replacing suspend with hibernate, and then [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/487282) (Ubuntu 16.04 and above, section). Not sure if only the second link would be enough but doing only the first did not help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have as much contiguous swap space as you have RAM?  `free` will tell you. If not, read `man mkswap swapon fstab`.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.