# Ubuntu takes too long to sleep?

Tags: 16.04, suspend

I have an **Ubuntu 16.04** on ***Asus K55VD*** and pressing <kbd>`Fn`</kbd>+<kbd>`F1`</kbd> to put it to sleep takes too long (up to 10 or 15 seconds) while running `systemctl suspend` will normally take less than 5 seconds.

Comment: Is hybrid sleep enabled and associated with that key combo? See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend/781957?r=SearchResults#781957) for more.

Comment: Will enabling hybrid sleep make sleep process faster or slower?

Comment: Hybrid sleep will make it slower. First, it writes the stuff in RAM to hard drive. Then it goes to sleep. Therefore, it takes longer with hybrid sleep.

Comment: I've no `sleep.conf` and all the lines in `logind.conf` are commented.