# What is hybrid suspend

Tags: suspend, hybrid

What is hybrid suspend? 
Please also add other info such as packages, etc. A how-to would be great too.

Comment: How to is already available on AU: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what it is exactly?

Comment: Yes it is a special kind of suspend. some more info here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1685/whither-hybrid-suspend see the comment with (now) +3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
   pm-suspend-hybrid
       Hybrid-suspend is the process where the system does everything it
       needs to hibernate, but suspends instead of shutting down. This
       means that your computer can wake up quicker than for normal
       hibernation if you do not run out of power, and you can resume even
       if you run out of power. s2both(8) is an hybrid-suspend
       implementation.
```

Answer (score 4):

Hybrid suspend is when your computer does suspend-to-disk and suspend-to-RAM at the same time. So you get the fast resume speed of suspend-to-RAM, but you don't lose your session if you lose power or run out of battery. So in principle, it's better than either suspend-to-ram or suspend-to-disk alone.

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1685/whither-hybrid-suspend) question

Thanks to [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) for the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219141/what-is-hybrid-suspend#comment270846_219141)