# Hibernate while in sleep on critical battery

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate

Is there any way to configure Ubuntu 22.04 to hibernate on some critical battery percentage, say 5%, when already in sleep? Suppose you go to sleep at 20% battery and remain in sleep for a long time so the battery eventually drains. Is there any way to prevent that by hibernating while in sleep?

I know I can hibernate while in sleep after a predefined delay but that's not what I want.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David 22.04 jammy

Comment: See the ["Ubuntu 16.04 and Above" section of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend/781957#781957)  Also see the ["In Ubuntu 17.10 and below hybrid-sleep was the closest" part of this ansser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048159/does-linux-have-a-hybrid-deep-sleep-mode-like-the-mac/1048196#1048196). What you want is `hybrid-sleep`. It does not work exactly the way you want, but does pretty much the same thing.