# Hybrid Suspend in 14.04?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, hybrid

Hybrid suspend was working in 13.10 before upgrade, but no longer.   Tried both methods mentioned here  [How do I use pm-suspend-hybrid by default instead of pm-suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145443/how-do-i-use-pm-suspend-hybrid-by-default-instead-of-pm-suspend)  but no luck

Test for support turns up good, pm-suspend  and pm-hibernate both work as expected, I just cannot get it to transition from suspend to hibernate on its own.

Machine is Thinkpad t430s.

Does anyone have this working in 14.04 that could share their config?

thanks!

Comment: So to confirm - it suspends (and resumes) OK, but never goes from suspend to hibernate?  That matches what I am seeing too.

Comment: Hi Greg, that's correct, suspend works fine, hibernate works fine, but I cannot get it to do hybrid and go from suspend to hibernate.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue, there is a Bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1318249), there is also a related question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1685/whither-hybrid-suspend?rq=1) at askubuntu, but so far, didn't find someone who actually got it fixed.

Comment: Are you using disk encryption?

Answer (score 0):

For a "true" hybrid suspend, which writes the image to both disk and RAM from the beginning, having the benefits that resuming will always be fast and that the machine will not wake up for a short time to hibernate for real. To use it, instead of he code above, paste the following in the **/etc/pm/config.d/00-use-suspend-hybrid** file:

```
# WORKAROUND: always set the default hibernate mode first (normal mode)
# (not required if you have the patch mentioned by Rohan below (http://askubuntu.com/a/344879/169))
HIBERNATE_MODE=platform

# Always use hibernate instead of suspend, but with "suspend to both"
if [ "$METHOD" = "suspend" ]; then
METHOD=hibernate
HIBERNATE_MODE=suspend
fi

# Make sure to use the kernel's method, in case uswsusp is installed etc.
SLEEP_MODULE=kernel
```